# Who is this quote from?

Tags: identify-this, quotations

My memory tells me that this quote:

> Whenever someone says that he is better than me, I checkmate him

is from Capablanca. But I haven't been able to find it. So maybe it isn't from him or that quote never existed.

Do you know this or a very similar quote like this one and who said it?

Comment: According to a quick google and a facebook site it was Lasker saying "In chess, if anybody claims he is better than I, I can checkmate him" But I can't find a reliable source - and both forms may be a translation of the original German (which I don't speak). If it was said it sounds more like Lasker to me.

Comment: I tried too, no chance with some random backtranslations and googling...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quote by Emanuel Lasker. I found the source to be
[The Adventure of Chess](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/The_Adventure_of_Chess/o0RaAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22I%20can%20checkmate+him%22&printsec=frontcover), a 1950 book published by Edward Lasker. The quote given is:

> In mathematics, if I find a new approach to a problem, another mathematician might claim that he has a better, more elegant solution. In chess, if anybody claims he is better than I, I can checkmate him

Edward says Emanuel once told him this.